# My code does not read from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I've tried to debug this times without success. Here is what I've tried so far

```
<?php
$cid= (string)$_GET['cid'];//I passed this from another page using get method
echo $cid; //My code works up to this point
$record = mysql_query("select * from questions where QType = '$cid'");
$array = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($record))
        {
            $array[] = $row;
        }
    for($var = 0; $var<count($array);$var++)
        {
        echo $array[$var]['Question'].'<br>';

        }           
            ?>
```

Comment: and what error do you get? have you try your query directly ?

Comment: **Attention:** Your queries are highly in **danger** of getting injected!! See [How can I prevent SQL injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1)

Comment: `$array[$var]['Question']` all your columns are named `Question`?

Comment: `print_r($array)`

Comment: mysql_* is closed in php7, can u plz chk your connection

Comment: The mysql extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used

Comment: **suggestion:** no need to use `for($var = 0; $var<count($array);$var++)` you can do it with `while`

Comment: check your PHP version also, and check your connection too.

Comment: @sfili_81, I didn't get any error.

Comment: roullie, just one of the columns

Comment: what is one column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will work and is a bit safer

```
<?php
//Connection part
$servername = "server_adress"; //It can be localhost or 127.0.0.1 or some other IP
$username = "XXXXXX"; //Username for DB
$password = "YYYYYY"; //Password for that user
$database = "ZZZZZZ"; //DB name you are connecting to

//Create a new connection
$conn_to_db = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$database);

// Check connection
if ($conn_to_db -> connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn_to_db ->connect_error);
}

//Finished connection part

$cid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn_to_db, $_GET['cid']); //Escapes special characters in a string for use in an SQL statement

$array = array();

if($stmt = $conn_to_db -> ("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE QType = ?")) {
   $stmt -> bind_param("s", $cid);
   $stmt -> execute();
   $stmt -> bind_result($question_from_db);  //Here you can put all variables you are fetching from DB
   while($stmt -> fetch()){
     //Iterate over rows - put your code here to fetch everything you need from DB and put in array
     $array[] = array('question' => $question_from_db);
   }   
   $stmt -> close();
 }
} 

//you can iterate over rows like this
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
 echo $value['question'];
}
?>
```

Couple of things to keep in mind:

- it's a good practice to avoid * (selecting everything from DB) and
  put only columns you need from DB
- use prepared statement which is a safer way and protects you from SQL injection
- MySQL is depreciated so try to avoid it (use mysqli or PDO)
- The code above you need to adjust to your needs! It will not work as copy/paste. Put your DB connection and select columns from DB you need and add variables which you fetch from DB
- Keep in mind there are more ways to do this, and someone will probably give another solution.
- if you are not on a production server, it's good to have some error reporting to see the errors that are happening

Comment: much better, also add connection part.